# Buy one specific product and get another specific product for free: 1 gift per one chargeable product

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I created rule for  "buy one specific product and get another specific product for free" (which works for me):

[image]

Only thing is that when I put chargeable product and two gift products in the shopping cart are both gift products on the website for free. Although, it should be one gift product for one chargeable product, 2 gift products for two chargeable products etc..

What should I do that customer gets for one chargeable product only one gift product for free?